# System can't find router on boot up

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, wireless-router

When I boot up (Windows XP) it doesn't recognize my router so I have to go into manage My Computer to "services & applications"  then to "services", then to "wireless zero configuration" and initiate "start".

How do I get my platform to recognize my router (wireless) right off the bat?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices when it comes to managing your wireless connections under Windows. Either you use Windows to handle connections or you have a third party app do the work.

From what you describe you don't have a third party app installed and your box is not configured to start the zero config utility at boot.

Whichever you choose, the service needs to be configured to automatically start when the PC boots.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that wireless is being managed by only one application. Also, make sure that the startup type is set to automatic.